# Using IN filters in OpenLayers?

Tags: filter, openlayers-2, comparison

Is there a way to use IN filters (like the IN operator from SQL) in OpenLayers 2?

For example, let's say, I want a filter like this:

```
city = 'Paris' OR city = 'London' OR city = 'Lisbon'
```

In OpenLayers, I would have to combine logical and comparison filters and it would be a big filter for only 3 cities. It would be something like this:

```
var filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
    filters: [
        new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
            property: 'city',
            type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
            value: 'Paris'
        }),
        new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
            property: 'city',
            type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
            value: 'London'
        }),
        new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
            property: 'city',
            type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
            value: 'Lisbon'
        })
    ],
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR
});
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do it like this:

```
var filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
    property: 'city',
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.IN,
    values: ['Paris', 'London', 'Lisbon']
});
```

I know that it does not work with OpenLayers, but how can I make it work?

Comment: CQL supports the IN clause. You might alternatively be able to create the functionality you want using OpenLayers.Filter.Function.

Comment: @drunkenwagoner, thanks for your answer... I never used OpenLayers.Filter.Function. how would you suggest doing this? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to override the `OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.prototype.evaluate` function in a way, that it will test whether `this.value` is an array and if yes, test whether `got` contains `exp` (for the `IN` case). To make it more clean, you should add your own `OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.IN` comparator to the enumerable.

See the original code to override in OpenLayers install package under `lib\OpenLayers\Filter\Comparison.js:112`, it's quite pretty!

Comment: hi @meehocz, thanks for your answer. Indeed, it might be the best solution, but I would prefer avoiding the overriding of methods from the OpenLayers core... do you think it would be possible with OpenLayers.Filter.Function? I never used this lass, so I don't know its potential

Comment: Hi @joaorodr84, if you don't want to override OL core, ThomasG77's answer is a nice way to go. However, if you override (or better said extend) the library carefully (I mean think about all possible consequences), there's no problem with that and you can use it in future. I have a separate file just for these OL extensions, so the original library is not touched.

Answer (score 1):

I really didn't look in the OpenLayers 2 API but you just need to know JavaScript to make it better. Just use [array manipulation functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) at Mozilla Developer Network documentation (MDN)

```
var towns = ['Paris', 'London', 'Lisbon'];
var inFilters = towns.map(function(el) {
  return new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
    property: 'city',
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
    value: el
  })
});

var filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
    filters: inFilters,
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR
});
```